# What are the detailed effects of carbon/hibernation sickness?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars, return-of-the-jedi

In RotJ, we can observe Han Solo suffering from an extended period of temporary blindness after at least half a year in carbon freeze.

In the Clone Wars, however, we see in this [clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FcerfE89IIc) that they recovered almost immediately, although they probably only were in hibernation for one hyperspace jump.

How do the effects of hibernation sickness change over time, as a person spends a longer duration frozen, in terms of the known effects suffered and their intensity and duration?

Comment: are you looking for canon answers? If so you probably already have all the information we do. If you're willing to accept Legends sources you should mention that in your question.

Answer (score 1):

According to the (new) novelisation of Return of the Jedi, the major symptoms of hibernation sickness are;

- **Exhaustion**
- **Weakness**
- **Dehydration**
- **Dizziness**
- **Memory loss**
- **Blindness.**

It also mentions that **death** can occasionally occur.

> *Since a common side effect was **death**, Solo is lucky to have only
> **exhaustion, weakness, dehydration, dizziness, memory loss, and
> blindness.***
>
> <sub><sup>[Return of the Jedi: Beware the Power of the Dark Side!](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Return_of_the_Jedi:_Beware_the_Power_of_the_Dark_Side!)</sup></sub>

This accords with what we see in the film series, albeit we should probably append the word "*temporary*" onto all of the symptoms (other than death) and yes, the length of time in hibernation does seem to impact on the severity of the symptoms.

Comment: Isn't there some Legends (?) canon that talks about (bad) dreams?

Comment: @Mazura - Yes, but I thought it better to stick to purely canon sources since it's so inconsistently portrayed in the various legends sources.

Comment: Wait, are we talking about hibernation sickness or the latest drug commercial? I can't tell